# use Perl to create variable names from the difference between two CSV columns

Tags: perl

I am trying to select the value from time `03:00:00` and subtract column 6 (4.86) from column 3 (89). (This is based on the second column, time.) The resulting value I need to turn into a variable name by appending letter `i` as a prefix:

```
2015-03-17,00:00:00,68,1003.08,7.85,7.853,
2015-03-17,03:00:00,89,1003.1,4.857,4.86,
2015-03-17,06:00:00,96,1000.74,3.78,3.782,
2015-03-17,09:00:00,95,999.48,3.2,3.2,
2015-03-17,12:00:00,95,1001.42,2.02,2.024,
2015-03-17,15:00:00,86,1005.77,0.49700000000001,0.5,
2015-03-17,18:00:00,75,1008.88,-0.13,-0.12899999999996,
2015-03-17,21:00:00,72,1010.85,-0.12199999999996,-0.12,
```

e.g. From the line with `03:00:00` in the second column, calculate `ROUNDED(col3 - col6)` (84) and then `CONCAT('i', value)` (if this was MySQL)

`@subvalue` would be `i84`

What I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
my $in_file = 'file.csv';      
open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die "could not open $in_file: $!\n";

my @column = map { $_->[2] } @{ $csv->getline_all($fh) };
print @column;

}
```

This obviously is extracting only a single column. For the appending I was looking at using join or even system ( "paste -d, since its in Linux)

Comment: Please clarify. For the first row, you want to subtract 7.853 from 1003.08 giving 995.227. Rounding that and prefixing `i` gives you `i995`. Is that correct? Do I understand correctly that you want to create a variable `$i995` from that? If so then you should be using a hash instead.

Comment: My mistake  it is 89 - 4.86 (col 3 - col 6).  I tried the script shown below:         use strict;
use warnings;
my $in_file = 'tortest.csv';

while ( $in_file ) {
  my @fields = split /,/;
  printf "i%.0f\n", @fields[3] - @fields[6];
}   and get got the following error Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at intend_parce.pl "

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you mean, <strike>however I don't see how you get `i84` from your data</strike>.

As for *"The resulting value I need to turn into a variable"* I think you mean to create a variable like <strike>`$i995`</strike> `i84`, but you don't say what you want to do with it and you would be better off using that string as a hash key.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = 'tortest.csv';
open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die qq{Unable to open "$in_file" for input: $!};

while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /,/;
  printf "i%.0f\n", $fields[2] - $fields[5];
}
```

**output**

```
i60
i84
i92
i92
i93
i86
i75
i72
```

---

**Update**

If you prefer to use `map` then it can be done like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = 'tortest.csv';
open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die qq{Unable to open "$in_file" for input: $!};

my @values = map {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /,/;
  sprintf "i%.0f", $fields[2] - $fields[5];
} <$fh>;

print "$_\n" for @values;
```

The output is identical to that of the program above.

Comment: My mistake  it is 89 - 4.86 (col 3 - col 6).  I tried the script shown below:            use strict;
use warnings;
my $in_file = 'tortest.csv';

while ( $in_file ) {
  my @fields = split /,/;
  printf "i%.0f\n", @fields[3] - @fields[6];
}   and get got the following error Use of uninitialized value in subtraction (-) at intend_parce.pl "

Comment: Okay I've altered my solution. The second line gives `89 - 4.86 = 84.14`, so the string is `i84`. Is that right? Your own solution is wrong because you have to *open* the input file and read each line from the file handle that you get.

Comment: That works great THANKS.  But how would I only get the value for the line of 03:00:00 or a different time?

Comment: It's hard to help without better understanding of your application, but in general terms you would qualify the `print` line. Something like `printf "i%.0f\n", $fields[2] - $fields[5] if $fields[1] eq '03:00:00'`

Comment: That does work. What I a doing is using perl to run a number of Mysql routines. Initially I was trying do the subtraction for the above columns and direct the output to a variable. The "i" value represents the column of another table but YOU CANT use a variable to represent a column in sql. You can for data and for table names.  So i was going to move it out to the perl script and introduce the dynamic variable there, which should work.

Comment: @BrianB You mean you have columns in your database named `i60`, `i84`, `i92`, etc? That sounds like a poor schema design. What does `i84` actually *represent*? Anyway, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That's okay, they're hard to avoid sometimes, but you'll probably get better answers if you take a step back and explain the problem you're actually trying to solve instead of how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: Its not the design this is an imported index that is necessary (a x/y calculator - so yes).  So the x matched with y provides a fixed value essential to the overall calculation. The subtraction was actually being done within Mysql between two columns and I was using concat to create i24. This value would be then be declared as the @variable representing a i24 column. My hope is to conduct this process in perl - the variable will be conducted outside of sql.  THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!